# Simple a href to a div not working

Tags: html, angularjs

This is my HTML and the nav is not working. 
This is new to me, the only thing I am doing different this time is using Angular. When I click in any nav button the address bar goes like

```
http://localhost:8018/#/WebDev
```

insted of

```
http://localhost:8018/#WebDev
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<head>
    <!-- Basic Page Needs
         –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DevMash</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
         –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
    <!-- FONT
         –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,400|Roboto+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- CSS
         –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">
    <!-- Favicon
         –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
    <!-- Scripts
    –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js\jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js\angular.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#WebDev">WebDev</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#Android">Android</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#Python">Python</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#faq">FAQs</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="WeDev"><ng-include src="'WebDev.html'"></ng-include></div>
    <div id="Android" ng-include="'android.html'"></div>
    <div id="Python" ng-include="'python.html'"></div>
    <div id="faq" ng-include="'faq.html'"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Update: I just want it to work as it does normally in HTML,ie, when  tag is clicked, the page should be directed to the target div.

Comment: i hope this is the desired output, angular works this way. Your urls look like #/state

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?  If you're trying to show/hide the divs based on the nav selection; you may considering looking into ngroute or some other Angular router.

Comment: desired output should be /#state. I dont want angular to work on it. I want this to behave like it does. The page should be directed to the div.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to do it in AngularJs Way if you are in an AngularJs environment. if you want to do it in a native way, then remove angularJs from your script.

For more detail, please see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll

Answer (score 0):

I replaced from href="#target" to href="##target". Seems to work.